# Trying to retrieve data using Eventbrite API with Node.js promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventbrite

I'm trying to get back an array of objects with Eventbrite events in a specific location, using promises with Node.js.

I'm using this system but I didn't see any positive results. Does anyone have a clue?

```js
var request = require('request');

//requesting API data 
function requestPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

//getting events from Eventbrite parsed as JSON
function getEvents() {
    var website = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/';
    var filter = 'd/canada--montreal/science-and-tech--events/';
    var token = 'oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=************';
    return (
        requestPromise(website + filter + token)
        .then(function(events) {
            var latestEvent = JSON.parse(events.body);
            return latestEvent; 

        })
    );
}

getEvents().then(function(events){
    console.log(events) ;   
    
});
```

Comment: Where is it failing?

Comment: It was failing at the authentication process, but I figured out a way to retrieve an array of objects with the information I needed. Thanks a lot!